# Finite number of jump discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a **monotonic** function. $t \in (a,b)$ is called a jump discontinuity of $f$ if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow t + } f(t) , \lim_{x \rightarrow t - } f(t)$ both exist but are not equal. In short, call these limits $f(x^+),f(x^-)$.

Let $X_n = \{ x \hspace{3mm} | \hspace{3mm} f(x^+) - f(x^-) \ge \frac{1}{n}\}$.

Prove or disprove that $X_n\text{ is finite}$.

I have been trying this problem. But, the validity of the statement does not seem intuitive for me. Please help me, by giving a proof, or an argument, or counter-example. I feel, $X_n$ might be countably infinite.

Comment: I'm imagining an infinite stair case with the width of the $m$'th stair being $1/2^m$, and each stair having height $1$.

Comment: Hint: since $(a,b)$ is open, $f$ can be unbounded. For example, you can place the desired jumps (of height at least $1/n$) at the positions $b-1/m$ for every $m \in \mathbb N$ large enough. So $X_n$ can be infinite.

Comment: This was exactly the argument that I used, and even found a counterexample. But, actually I was asked in an assignment to prove it. But, now it turns out, that the statement is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by

$\hspace{50mm} f(x) = n  \hspace{10mm} \text{where} \hspace{5mm} \frac{1}{n+1} \le x < \frac{1}{n}$.

This function has jump disconituities at points of the form $\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$. But all $X_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$ are infinite (countably). So the statement is not true in general. Of course, we can find functions where the statement is true, for e.g., continuous functions.

Comment: Other examples of such functions are provided in the comments to the question.